# React: react-google-charts timeline: displaying two different formats on the same axis

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-google-charts

Right now I'm trying to update an hourly timeline chart to use the following horizontal axis format:

- For the tick at the left side of the chart, or for any ticks where the date changes, use the format "EE HH:mm" (display day and time)
- Otherwise, just use the format "HH:mm" (just display time)

I've looked on stack overflow and at the google tutorials and have been unable to find any examples on how to do this.  Does anybody know how to use two different formats on the same axis?

Here's the current Chart object:

```
<Chart
      width="100%"
      chartType="Timeline"
      loader={<div>Loading Chart ...</div>}
      data={[metaData, ...passes]}
      options={{
        title: "timeline chart", 
        height: ch*41+100,
        hAxis: {
          format: "EE HH:mm",
          minValue: min,
          maxValue: max,
        }
      }}
    />
```

How can I have different formats for different ticks on the chart's horizontal axis?